# YII: Upload image without clicking on save button.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I want to upload image directly when user choose file from list through ajax. I don't want them to click on save button for uploading it.

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Profile Picture</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" name="profile_pic"/>
                <span class="login-error"><?php if (isset($error['profile_pic'])) echo $error['profile_pic'][0]; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php 
                    if(isset($model['profile_pic']))
                        echo '<img width="200" height="150" class="col-sm-4" src="/uploads/profile/'.$model['profile_pic'].'" alt="" />';
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my view code I've written.

Can anyone suggest me how I can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this? http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Log1c it would be good if it can be done without any plugin :)

Comment: Ok, then you'l need to bind `change()` event of file-input control using jQuery (or javascript) `$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
 //code to submit form, so it will start uploading
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Wrap your input element with `<form>` element:

```
<form id="fileForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?">
     <input id="picInput" type="file" name="profile_pic"/>
</form>
```

And add javascript:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var $form = $("#fileForm");

        $form.ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            success: function(src){
                    if (!src) return;

                    $("#picDiv").html('<img width="200" height="150" class="col-sm-4" src="/uploads/profile/'+src+'" alt="" />');
            }
        });

        $("#picInput").change(function(){
            $form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that I use `picDiv` and `picInput` IDs for div containing picture and input , so you need to add them to work properly.

In your Controller, output uploaded and saved file's name.